# How to pass id in Route React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to build a page when from list of products I want to see product by ID. In my App file I have something like that:

```
<Route path={ROUTES.product} element={<Product id={1} />}>
```

but I want to replace static id with the value that comes from the selected product. In my Product file I have redirection to page with product but I don't know how I can pass the ID.

```
onClick={() => { navigate(`/products/${product?.id}`)}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the ROUTES.product?

Comment: Its path in ROUTES.json file `"product": "/products/:id"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've provided appears to pass the `id` value in the path. It seems your question more about getting the `Product` component to have the correct `id` prop passed to it.

Given: path is `"/products/:id"`

Options to access the `id` param:

1. Use the `useParams` hook in `Product` to read the `id` route path param. This only works if `Product` is a function component.

   ```
   import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   ...

   const { id } = useParams();
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path={ROUTES.product} element={<Product />} />
   ```
2. Use a wrapper component to use the `useParams` hook and inject the `id` value as a prop. This is useful if `Product` is not a function component.

   ```
   import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

   const ProductWrapper = () = {
     const { id } = useParams();
     return <Product id={id} />
   };
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path={ROUTES.product} element={<ProductWrapper />} />
   ```
3. Create a custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to use the `useParams` hook and inject a `params` prop.

   ```
   import { useParams, ...other hooks... } from 'react-router-dom';

   const withRouter = Component => props => {
     const params = useParams();
     ... other hooks...
     return (
       <Component
         {...props}
         params={params}
         ... other hooks ...
       />
     );
   };
   ```

   ...

   Wrap `Product` with `withRouter` HOC and access `id` param from `props.params`

   ```
   props.params.id // or this.props.params

   ...

   export default withRouter(Product);
   ```

   ...

   ```
   <Route path={ROUTES.product} element={<Product />} />
   ```

Comment: I have a question to your answer: when I try to pass id in Route component `<Route path={ROUTES.info} element={<Product ProductID={id}/>}> ` I get an error: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'. When in my Product file I have something like this: `type Props = {
  ProductID: number;
};

const ProductDetailsView = ({ ProductID }: Props) => {
  const [products, setProduct] = useState<Product>();

  const { id } = useParams();`

Comment: @helloworld All route params will be of type String. If using any params for assignment to local variables/etc... they need to be converted to the correct matching types, for example, if all `id` values are numbers, use `productId={Number(id)}`. Or you can amend your type declaration to include sting types, i.e. `type props = { productId: number | string | null; };`. Does this make sense?

Comment: @helloworld Sorry, I'm no Typescript expert, but it might be `type props = { productId?: number | string; };` for optional props. Not sure if you still need `null` in there though.

Comment: @helloworld Oh, and sorry it it wasn't clear, all of the options I've presented remove sending any props at the route level, they each use the `useParams` hook to get the value, so the route doesn't pass anything additional to the component it's rendering.

Comment: Thank You, it makes more sense now. But I have additionaly one more question because as I can see the value that is passed to the backend is NaN. Do you know how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: @helloworld For this I think we'd need to see this `Product` component code ***and*** the product data being iterated and passing a value here `navigate(\`/products/${product?.id}\`)` to say why any value is `NaN` other than whatever you are converting *isn't* actually a number.

Comment: @helloworld Sorry, how is that question different from this one? It looks like the same exact issue of getting the `id` from the URL path. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I belive You are understanding it correctly and the problem is still with passing the `id` value. But I have no idea how to resolve this problem still.

Comment: @helloworld I think if you've implemented the solutions above though, you won't need to pass a prop at the route level `<ProductDetailsView id={Number(id)} />` as the wrapper/HOC/hook would have already accessed the `id` from the path directly or passed as a prop to the underlying component using it.

Answer (score 2):

so you already have the id with this

```
navigate(`/products/${product?.id}`)
```

just in Product component you can access id with

```
 const { id } = useParams();
```

if you need to pass extra data you can try:

```
navigate(`/product/${product?.id}`, { state: { someExtradata }};
```

that you can access state in the component with :

```
 const { state } = useLocation();
```

Comment: Do I need a Route component to redirect to page with product details?

Comment: it depends on your routing and product structure, but commonly yes.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, I can access id in such way in my App file: `<Route path={ROUTES.product} element={<ProductDetailsView id={id} />}> `?

Comment: no you just need to pass ProductDetailsView component in element and dose not needs pass id. then you will navigate to the product with `/products/${product?.id}`. In productDetailsView component you can access id from browser route with useParams.

Comment: accutly you have to get the id from route not pass it as props.

Comment: When I try to do something like this: `<Route path={ROUTES.product} element={<ProductDetailsView/>}> </Route>` I'm getting an error that property id is missing. And when commenting out this Router section I'm getting blank page.

Comment: How can I get id from route?

Comment: it is probably because of you ProductDetauksView accept id as props. so you need to remove the id props and get the id from useParams. check this https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview#reading-url-parameters

Answer (score -1):

```
onClick={ () => Navegar(id) }
function Navegar(id) {
    navigate('/products/id)
}
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.