# Access /:id in functional component from URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a Blog app and I am trying to pass id with url for open `detail page of blog` so I created `Route Link` with id But I have no idea How can I access it from url ? or How can I retrieve id passed in url ?

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            ...
            <Route path='/blog-detail/:id' element={<BlogDetail/>} />
            ...
         </div>
      )
   }
}

function Blogs() {
   return (
         <div>

             {
               blogs.map(blog => 
              <div>
                   {blog.title}

                   <Link to={`/blog-detail/:${blog.id}`}>Open Blog</Link>
              </div>
             }

         </div>
   )
}


// Trying to access id passed in this component
function BlogDetail() {
   return (
         <div>

             Will display blog detail data from Backend by id


         </div>
   )
}
```

I have tried many times But it is still not working.

- I could easily access by using `window.location.href` and `slice` after `/` But I think that would not efficient.
- I can also pass `state={{ id: blog_id }}` using `Link` and access through `useLocation` But What if user doesn't click from `Blog Component` and input directly from browser.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass id in Route React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72004170/how-to-pass-id-in-route-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';

const params = useParams();
console.log(params); // {id: '1'}
```

Also there are more info here : [How to pass id in Route React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72004170/how-to-pass-id-in-route-react)

Comment: That is a really good option

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useParamHook to get the parameter at the end of the route

```
const {id} = useParams();
```

This should help you get the id at the end of the route

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write BlogDeatils component as below:

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
....

function BlogDetail() {
    const { id } = useParams();


    return (
          <div>

            Blog id is {id}
 
          </div>
    )
 }
```